# Nvarchar(Max) column to DateTime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to migrate some date from old database to a new database.

In the old database, there is a column that type is `nvarchar(max)` and the data in that column is like `26/03/2022`

But this data I want to insert into the column in the new database and that column is `Datetime` type.

Can you show me how to convert it to the DateTime format.?

Comment: What's wrong with the aptly named `CONVERT` function?

Comment: I will admit, however, that if your "date" data is stored in an `nvarchar(MAX)` then the designer was *explicitly* stating that the "date" was likely to be 4,000 or more characters long; what "date" data do you have where this is true, and what "date" is that value?

Comment: Double check that **ALL** the values in the column follow this format consistently. If they do, this is simple enough. If they do not, you're in for some pain.

Comment: What do you want to do with values in that column that _cannot_ be converted to a date? Insert NULL? Skip them? Maybe you want to take a sample of them first (e.g. `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, COALESCE(col_name, '01/01/2000'), 103) IS NULL;`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '26/03/2022', 103)
```